# Marking files as config files in CPack

Tags: rpm-spec, cpack

When creating RPM packages: How do I tell CPack to treat a file as config file so it won't get overridden when updating the RPM?

The *%config* directive is used in rpm-spec for that case. Is there something like this in CPack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at what appears to be the `CPack` documentation doesn't show me anything that looks like it is directly relevant or helpful here.

However, if you are using a new enough version of CMake (2.8.1+ it looks like) or apply the patch yourself it looks like you can manually specify the spec file to build by using [`CPACK_RPM_USER_BINARY_SPECFILE`](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackPackageGenerators#CPack_RPM_generators_specific_settings).

Comment: Up to now, this seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, files specified with an absolute path will get marked with %config, files with a relative path are marked as 'normal' files.